# Using a cookie to display a popup after a certain amount of pages have been clicked

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display a popup modal after a user has clicked on a certain amount of pages.

Currently, this is the code I have.

```
function BlackFridayPopup() {

    if (isMobile) return;
    if (!$('body').hasClass('homepage') && getCookie('page_count') != 3) return;

    $(window).on('load', function () {
        if (getCookie('blackFridayPopup')) return;

        setCookie('blackFridayPopup', '1', '7');
        $('#myModel').modal('show');
    });
}
```

The page count function works fine and counts as it should.

Any help or suggestions would be great!

Comment: code seems fine... Do you get any error?? console log

Comment: please, paste your functions: getCookie() and setCookie()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cookie "blackFridayPopup" is always null. So your function is returning.

You need to check if the value is null, and if not, to return.

Like this:

```
function BlackFridayPopup() {
    if (isMobile) return;
    if (!$('body').hasClass('homepage') && getCookie('page_count') != 3) return;

    $(window).on('load', function () {
        if (!getCookie('blackFridayPopup')){
           setCookie('blackFridayPopup', '1', '7');
           $('#myModel').modal('show');
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
}
```